# iBatis statements externalization

Tags: java, xml, ibatis

I have iBatis xml config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
<sqlMap> 

    <resultMap id="dataResult" class="...skipped...">
    ...skipped...
    </resultMap>

    <procedure id="dataPull" resultMap="dataResult" >
        {call RealtimeDataPull ()}
    </procedure>

    <update id="updateTrades" parameterClass="...skipped...">
        UPDATE ...skipped... where ...skipped...
    </update>

</sqlMap>
```

Here I need to externalize DB stored procedure name `RealtimeDataPull` and `UPDATE` SQL statement. I gonna put them into regular java property file.

How can I do this in iBatis xml config correctly?

I've tried to define parameters like this

```
<procedure id="dataPull" resultMap="dataResult" >
    ${sql.dataPullCall}
</procedure>

<update id="updateTrades" parameterClass="...skipped...">
    ${sql.updateTradesStatement}
</update>
```

and put parameters in properties file

```
sql.dataPullCall={call RealtimeDataPull ()}
sql.updateTradesStatement=UPDATE ...skipped... where ...skipped...
```

but this `${...}` approach doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my problem is to use iBatis custom property files including and don't use standard Spring approach

```
<sqlMapConfig>
    <properties resource="sql.properties" />
    <sqlMap resource="dbMapping.xml"/>
</sqlMapConfig>
```